How to get compiling error for setting an object value in Angular's readonly signal?
I'm declaring a readonly signal of the type Signal:
public mySignal = signal({ id: 1 }).asReadonly();

But i get no compiling errors if I assign a different value in the signal. I expect the compiler to catch this error. I do get a runtime error, but that is often too late and i might not catch that.
this.mySignal().id = 1; // no compile error - i expect a compile error here

I expect a compile error when assigning a new value to a readonly signal.

Regular objects are mutable. As you can see in the linked duplicate question, in TypeScript you can mark an object as immutable with the as const expression: public mySignal = signal({ id: 1 } as const).asReadonly();

I see, but it can only be used on object literals. If im using ngrx selectSignal with a ngrx selector, then i can't use as const.

There are also other answers to this question which introduce a DeepReadonly helper type. This should help you with your NgRx use cases.

I see. I don't want to add more types and boilercode to the code, so I believe a custom ESLint rule is the way to go in my case - thanks.
